# Add a comment on .htpasswd

Tags: syntax, .htpasswd

I was wondering if it is possible to write a comment on the `.htpasswd` file.

Why ? Because sometimes, we have to "disable" some users, just for a couple of days. I checked on StackOverflow and other websites, and it seems pretty confusing :

- Not possible
- Possible with `::`
- Possible with `#` (like .htaccess)

`::bar:$apr1$G3iw8iqc$IGNoXDw7e7HolcSgE/V0a0`

`#foo:$apr1$3dJLDmbn$/zODUbSXmqDfeeCmMFKO8/`

*NB: I don't want to disable users by adding a fake char at the beginning of the line, for instance. I want a clean way, if this is possible ;)*

After testing, both seems to work, but I want some expert opinions (and btw VIm doesn't syntax highlight neither `::` nor `#`)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Apache's config file format (of which `.htaccess` files are one example) doesn't technically support inline comments, only full-line comments (i.e. a line *beginning* with a `#`).

> Lines that begin with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored. Comments may not be included on a line after a configuration directive. -- [Official Apache 2.4 manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the syntax of these files is the same as other Apache configuration files. Apache does not document this specifically for `.htpasswd`, but [says generically](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#htaccess) that comments can be added to their config files by using `#`. Comments can only span one line. Directives must be on one line, but can span multiple lines when appended with `\` at the end of the line.